# How can you benefit from the new System.Buffers (Span, Memory) when doing File I/O and parsing

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, .net-5

I'm currently looking at the new System.Buffers with Span, ReadOnlySpan, Memory, ReadOnlyMemory, ...

I understand when passing e.g. a ReadOnlySpan (ROS) this could reduce heap allocations in many cases and make code perform better. Most examples regarding Span show you the .AsSpan(), .Slice(...) examples but that's it.

Once I have my data (e.g. byte[]) then I can create a Span or ReadOnlySpan from it and pass that to several methods/classes inside my library.

But how can File I/O be writting using System.Buffers (Span/Memory/..)?

I've tried to created two small (partial) examples to demonstrate the situation.

```
// Example 1: 

using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(pathToFile)) {
  ReadFile(br);
}

private void ReadFile(BinaryReader br) {
   ParseHeader(...);
}

private void ParseHeader(BinaryReader br) {
  br.ReadBytes(...);
  br.ReadInt32();
  // ...
}
```

and

```
// Example 2:

public Foo GetFileAsFoo(string path) {
   using (var s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) {
      return ReadAndGetFoo(s);
   }
}

public Foo ReadAndGetFoo(Stream file) {
  // copy to memorystream as filestream file I/O is slow
  var ms = new MemoryStream();
  file.CopyTo(ms);
  ms.Position = 0;

  Parser p = new Parser(ms);
  p.Read();
  return p.GetFoo();
}


public class Parser {

   private readonly Stream _s;
   public Parser(Stream stream) {
       _s = stream;
    }

  int Peek() { 
     if (_s.Position >= _s.Length) return -1;

     int r = _s.ReadByte();
     _s.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
     return r; 
  }

  public void Read() {
    // logic here
  }

  public Foo GetFoo() {
    // ...
    return _Foo;
  } 
  // other methods to parse
}
```

The question for the first example is mainly on how can I get a ReadOnlySpan/Memory/...(?) from:

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
```

I'm aware of System.Buffers.Binary.BinaryPrimites to replace the BinaryReader, but this requires a ReadOnlySpan. How would I get my data from File.OpenRead as span in the first place, similar as I do with the BinaryReader?

What options are available?

I guess there is no class in the BinaryPrimities that keeps track of the 'position' similar as a BinaryReader does?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-5.0

The second example instead of working with a BinaryReader is working on a Stream.
To keep it efficient, I first do a copy to a memorystream to reduce the I/O. (I know this one-time copy is slow and should be avoided).

How could this File as Stream be read the using System.Buffers (Span/Memory/...?) ?
(byte per byte is being read and parsed using Stream.ReadByte())

Hope to learn something!

Comment: You can load the file into `byte[]` capped at disc read speed, So i'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. If you don't read the file into memory then you have to constantly seek inside the file on disk with a file handle.

Comment: Trying to figure out how File I/O could be done with the System.Buffers to benefit from performance, less disk I/O and less heap-allocations for e.g. my two cases (or in general).

(1) BinaryReader is easy that it keeps track of the position

(2) Stream reeds byte per byte (in my case)